# Windows 7 search results can't be moved (cut option in pop-up menu disabled) - why? and how to enable it? (Was in XP!)

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I want to *move* a selection of files from a Windows 7 search to another folder but the right-click pop-up menu option for cut is disabled, why? Only copy is possible and I don't wish to make more than one copy of the files.

This cut facility from search results was available in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I use would be to copy the files to a separate folder and then use beyond compare to diff these with the original location to remove them from there. The only issue to overcome would be if there is more than one file with the same name, Windows will append an instance e.g. File (1).txt and so the beyond compare won't be able to directly compare with the origina without some extra steps. This can be overcome by using regexp as stated here:

http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showpost.php?s=1e2534c90a2d45e1298797eb946cbb17&p=28751&postcount=7

...which is the solution in the Scooter Software/Beyond Compare forum post: "Compare files with partially matching file names?": http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=28696